# Solving $\int{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}x$ using integration by parts, given that $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+k$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

Here is the question once again:

> Deduce the integral $\int{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}x$ using **integration by parts**, given the following identity: $$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+k$$

I know that the integral can be solved by using trigonometric substitutions, but I am looking for another way as that's not what is asked in the question.

Here is what I have done so far:

$$\int{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}x=x \cdot \sqrt{x^2+1}-\underbrace{\int{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \ \mathrm{d}x}}_{\text{$I_1$}}$$

$$I_1=x^2 \cdot \ln{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}-\underbrace{\int{\ln{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}\cdot 2x \ \mathrm{d}x}}_{\text{$I_2$}}$$

Solving $I_2$ using integration by parts gives an expression which includes $I_1$ so I got into a loop. I'm out of ideas so I would be glad if you could help me out, thank you for your time.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{(x^2 + 1)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$\int \sqrt {x^2 + 1} \ \Bbb d x = \int (x')\sqrt {x^2 + 1} \ \Bbb d x = x \sqrt {x^2 + 1} - \int x \frac {x} {\sqrt {x^2 + 1}} \ \Bbb d x = \\
x \sqrt {x^2 + 1} - \int \frac {x^2 + 1 -1} {\sqrt {x^2 + 1}} \ \Bbb d x = x \sqrt {x^2 + 1} - \int \sqrt {x^2 + 1} - \frac 1 {\sqrt {x^2 + 1}} \ \Bbb d x = \\
- \int \sqrt {x^2 + 1} \ \Bbb d x + x \sqrt {x^2 + 1} + \ln (x + \sqrt {x^2 + 1})$$

whence it follows that

$$2 \int \sqrt {x^2 + 1} \ \Bbb d x = x \sqrt {x^2 + 1} + \ln (x + \sqrt {x^2 + 1}) $$

so that

$$\int \sqrt {x^2 + 1} \ \Bbb d x = \frac 1 2 x \sqrt {x^2 + 1} + \frac 1 2 \ln (x + \sqrt {x^2 + 1}) + C$$

where $C \in \Bbb R$ is an arbitrary integration constant added at the end of the calculations.